# Display Browsable 3D models in Browser

Tags: browser, 3d, sketchup, vrml

**Statement:** I have a 3D model ready in Google SketchUp Pro.

**Problem Statement:**

1. I need to display the model in a webpage.
2. I need the model to be browsable (The user can navigate his way through it like on Google Earth)
3. I need the model to be update-able (If I update something in SketchUp, I should be able to easily port changes till the webpage)

**Question:** How can this be done?

Note: I figured out VRML could be an option, but I was unable to get that idea up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you investigated the [Sketchup Web Exporter](http://sketchup.google.com/download/plugins.html#gsuwebexporter) plugin (still in beta at time of writing)?

If that doesn't do exactly what you're after, you can write a plugin yourself using the [Sketchup API](http://sketchup.google.com/community/developers.html), allowing you to write plugins in Ruby or C++.

Comment: Wow! This is great! :) :) I can probably use it in many other places However, here I needed a little greater interactivity, as I said, much like what Google Earth 3D Plugin provides. Any Idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can now use SketchUp in the browser, and it should be able to read anything coming from SketchUp Pro. Check out https://my.sketchup.com